# Is there a routine in MKL to tranpose matrix in CSR format?

Tags: multidimensional-array, multiprocessing, fortran90

I simply need to transpose a square matrix in compressed sparse row (CSR) (stored over multiple processors), in a program that makes heavy use of the MKL library. I found a routine to do it, but was interested in seeing if there is an MKL library routine.

One way to look at it is as a conversion from CSR to CSC (compressed sparse column) format. I am given the routine that creates the CSR matrix; it is quite complex and I do not want to change it.

Thanks!

Tom

Answer (score 1):

mkl contains matrix format converters.  mkl_?csrcsc will go from csr to csc and vice versa.  This is the easiest way that I have found to transpose a sparse matrix in csr format.